# Передача данных из формы на одной странице в другую форму на другой странице

Tags: php, javascript, html, формы

Необходимо передать данные из одной формы html на одной странице в другую форму html на другой странице. Другая страница открывается по кнопке submit в форме на первой странице, в ней форма с уже заполненными полями из соответствующих полей первой страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Для передачи данных между формами можно воспользоваться методом `POST`.

*Пример реализации:*

Создаете первую форму, например, так:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
   <p>Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
   <p>Ваш возраст: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Где:

1. `action.php` - другая страница/файл, куда вы будете передавать
   значения (можете установить свой вариант)
2. Все что находится в между `<form> ... </form>` - задаете для себя, какие поля вам нужны.
3. Последний элемент - передача по `sumbit`, обязателен.

На следующем шаге создаете в файле `action.php` (или ваш вариант) и получаете данные,например, таким образом:

```
<form>
   <p> Имя: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>.</p>
   <p> Возраст: <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?> </p>
</form>
```

Здесь именно важна суть какая, что вы передаете глобальный массив `$_POST[]`, и все поля с заданными `name` в связке со значением "укладываются" в массив и передаются.

При обращении `$_POST['name']` вы получите данные, которые передали на первой форме через `<input type="text" name="name" />` (остальные по аналогии).

Comment: Попробовал сделать так, но на странице, куда передаю значения, ничего не отобразилось :(

Comment: @AlbertIdrisov прикрепите обе формы к вопросу, будем разбираться.

Comment: собственно, попробовал проверить формы, которые вы предложили как пример и на другую страницу данные не передались.

Comment: Понял свою ошибку и уже исправил. Вторую страницу нужно было открыть с расширением php, а не html, как я делал. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо сделать форму, которая при нажатии на submit передает данные с формы через POST или GET как вам удобнее, там вы их ловите например &_POST['name'], и например засовываете в скрытые поля, на второй странице у вас есть дополнительные поля, далее делаете тоже самое только уже + новые данные пока у вас логика формы постраничной не дойдет до конца.

Собственно все. Ничего сложного.